# how to make multiple remote calls with formvalidation.io validation

Tags: javascript, validation, formvalidation.io

I have a form I'm trying to validate a certain field first with a remote call for a required validation then a different remote call for a warning validation. I found an example of using two remote calls with an alias at this page: https://github.com/formvalidation/support/issues/310

It seems extremely straightforward, however, when I try this it does not work. Only one of the remote validations gets called. Using either one of the remotes by itself without an "alias" works but using the "alias" doesn't work. I am using formvalidation.io v0.7.0 which according to this article is supposed to support the "alias"

Am I approaching this wrong? Is this "alias" idea not a real option? Any help would be appreciated. As a workaround I also tried a getJSON inside a callback validation but it seemed like there were timing issues.

Here is my code:

```
 //Form validation setup
$form.formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',

    // Feedback icons 
    icon: {
        valid: 'fa fa-check',
        invalid: 'fa fa-remove',
        validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
    },

    fields: {
        ctl00$kcMasterPagePlaceHolder$TextBoxCaseNumber: {
            trigger: 'blur',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Case Number is Required'
                },
                remote:{
                    message: 'Case Number does not exist. Please contact XXXXX',
                    url: function(validator, $field, value) {
                        return './handlers/ServiceInterface.ashx?apistring=api/case/1234';
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    data: function(validator, $field, value) {
                        return {
                            valid: true
                        };
                    }
                }, // end remote

                my_remote:{
                    alias: "remote",
                    message: 'Warning: There is already an event for this case on this calendar!',
                    url: function(validator, $field, value) {
                        var strArguments = "1234";

                        return './handlers/ServiceInterface.ashx?apistring=api/event?casenumber=' + strArguments ;
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    data: function(validator, $field, value) {
                        return {
                            valid: true
                        };
                    }
                } // end remote
            }
        }
```

// leaving out the rest of the fields ...

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: yes, sorry to not update this post yet. The issue was not in the code posted but in the on success handler.  I was not checking the right remote name in the right part of the handler.